# Hidden "active" bootstrap tabs causing my page to scroll to the bottom on load

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

```
<div class="panel">
    <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#aboutInfo" data-toggle="tab">Info</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content clearfix">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="aboutInfo">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="aboutNavTitle">Page Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="aboutNavTitle" type="text" value="About Us">
            </div>
            <label for="summernote1">Text</label>
            <div class="summernote-container">
                <div id="summernote1">
                    ........
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a few of these panels, but it seems the ones with only one tab are causing the issue. They only have one tab for now, but down the road more will be added. If i remove the 'active' class from the tab-pane div, the page loads normally and doesn't scroll to the bottom upon load, but then my initial content is hidden and only the tab name shows. All of these panels are actually hidden and then shown when specific options are chosen.

Comment: Are you sure that all the `tabs` and `tabscontent` have his own unique Id?

Comment: I see also `summernote` are you using the summernote plugin in order to edit those contents?

Comment: @Franco yeah, in some of them i'm using the summernote plugin for a some editable content.

Comment: @Franco i double checked and every tab has a unique id

Comment: Would you mind posting this on JSFiddle or something? If not, have you considered the possibility that something in your JS/jQuery is triggering an autofocus on the `input` element, sending you tumbling down to the focused element?

Comment: How and where do you are attaching the summernote plugin to the editable elements

Comment: @Franco script tag initializing the summernote. i removed it from the above code because i had determined that it wasn't causing the scrolling issue.